# NGINX page shows raw content instead of HTML

Tags: php, html, nginx, http-headers, fpm

I am using NGINX 1.12 with PHP-FPM on AWS server.

I get a rare scenario bug that sometimes my page shows the html content along with headers with 0 prefixed and suffixed

```
0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 05:29:29 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

html content
0
```

When i refresh immediately or later, this will show the proper page.

Can anyone suggest what may be the issue ?

Comment: You might be better off at: http://serverfault.com

Comment: Looks like some sort of weird chunked encoding issue?